# Arduino to Python read in Real time -> AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute

Tags: python, arrays, excel, arduino

I have a problem with my code. I am supposed to need to plot the sensor values in real time, and then these values are saved to an excel document.

I tried to make an array, but when the codes run I get this message:

**AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'value'**

So I don't know if the loop is wrong or the array. Please help :(

````
def getSerialData(self, Samples, numData, serialConnection, lines):
    for i in range(numData):
      value = float(serialConnection.readline().strip()) #lee el sensor
      data[i].append(value) #guarda la lectura de la ultima posicion
      lines[i].set_data(range(Samples), data[i])

ts = 0.1
tf = 30
t = np.arange(0,tf+ts,ts)
N = len(t)

try:
  serialConnection = serial.Serial(serialPort, baudRate)
except:
  print('Not Connected')

for k in range(N):
  start_time = time.time()
  
  for i in range(numData):
    y[i,k] = serialConnection.value[i]
    data.append(collections.deque([0]*Samples, maxlen=Samples))
    lines.append(Line2D([], [], color ='red'))
    
  print(f"Voltage 1 {y[0,k]}")
  print(f"Voltage 2 {y[1,k]}")
          
  elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
  time.sleep(ts-elapsed_time)```
````